# ¿Cómo puedo conectar una base de datos SQL con COBOL?

Tags: sql, cobol

Desde hace algún tiempo busco la forma de escribir instrucciones SQL dentro de un archivo de Cobol. El problema es que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

He visto ejemplos añadiendo trozos de código EXEC-SQL pero no consigo que compile y tampoco se comp establecer la conexión con la base de datos.
No encuentro un curso o libro que se dedique a hacer esto.

Utilizo OpenCobolIDE.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que hace tiempo de tu pregunta, pero te voy a contestar por si le sirve a alguien:
Tienes que utilizar la librería **ESQL** para VisualStudio, que es un precompilador, lo que hace es que tú pones el código en SQL conectado a un controlador ODBC y lo convierte al formato OpenCobol antes de compilarlo.
La puedes encontrar aquí: http://www.kiska.net/opencobol/esql/, también hay versión para linux.
Y aquí https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/blob/master/doc/source/advanced.rst como integrarla.
Y aquí https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/contrib/thread/4057115f/ tienes ejemplos de código y como utilizarla.

Comment: Perfecto. Aún sigo con esa duda. Lo probaré con calma. Por cierto, me he descargado el enlace que pone: Version 3 VS 2019 project and Sources y no sé como añadirlo a VS

Comment: En uno de los enlaces que te he puesto, pone como añadirlo a VS.